# Torsion-free quotient group of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $H\leq G$. Prove that if $G/H$ is torsion-free, then $H$ contains the torsion group of $G$.

Proof:

Let $x\neq1$ be an element in the torsion group. Thus there exist $k\in \mathbb{N} $ with $x^k=1$.

Now we look at $(xH)^k = x^kH = H $

$G/H$ is torsion-free, so $xH$ must be equal to $H$ and therefore $x\in H $, as we wanted.

My question is that: In this proof I didn't really use the fact that $G$ is abelian. I could assume only that $H\lhd G$ and the proof still stands. Is it true?

Comment: You might want to add to the actual question the assumption that $G$ is finite, not just leave it in the tags.

Comment: @Asaf, It was a mistake, $G$ could be inifinite.

Comment: If $G$ is not abelian, then the torsion elements might not form a subgroup. For example if $G = \langle x,y\ |\ x^2 = y^2 = e\rangle$, then $x$ and $y$ are torsion elements, but $xy$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Wheeler says in the comments, we cannot generally speak of the torsion subgroup of groups that are not abelian, because the torsion points need not be closed under multiplication; an obvious example being the infinite dihedral group. On the other hand the proof you've written *does* demonstrate that all torsion points are contained in $H$.

It is possible for non-abelian groups to have torsion subgroups, of course. If $G$ is finite then the torsion points are just all of $G$, for instance, and Wikipedia [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup#Examples_and_further_results) that the torsion subset of any nilpotent group forms a normal subgroup (so this would include infinite groups). The orders of elements do not behave predictably in nonabelian settings, however: whereas in abelian groups we have that the order of $ab$ is the $\rm lcm$ of the orders of $a$ and $b$, we can actually pick any integers $r,s,t$ and there will be a group $G$ with elements $a,b,ab$ of those orders respectively (this is Thm 1.64 in [Milne's freely available group theory course notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html)), specifically the $\rm PSL_2$s of some finite fields.

Comment: No, $2mnr|(q-1)$ and $|\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}|=q-1$, as in the notes, are correct. As defined in the notes, $q$ is a power of $p$, i.e., $q=p^a$ for some integer $a$. It is not the exponent.

Comment: There is no typo in the notes (at least not in regard to that). $\mathbb{F}_q$ is generally used to denote the field of $q = p^k$ elements for some fixed $p$ and $k$.

Comment: @BrandonCarter You are correct, for some reason I read "some power of it, say $q$," to mean $p^q$, even though I've seen $q=p^r$ so many times... very silly of me.

Comment: One may add, since you mention nilpotency, that in the nilpotent case one *can* give bounds on the order of $ab$ in terms of the orders of $a$ and $b$ *and* the nilpotency class.

Comment: @anon: Sorry for misunderstanding what the situation was with the off-answer. (Yes, I know "anon" is short of anonymous). Since comments don't come with icons, at first I thought the comment you posted was by the OP; then I realized it was by you, but rather than *overwrite* my impression I simply appended the new information to it...